# Remove id from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe of a certain page from a site that I'm using, but I don't want all the parts of that page to be displayed with the iframe. Particularly, there's a navigation sidebar on the page that I don't want to be in the iframe. I'm trying to achieve this with the javascript seen below, but I can't quite figure it out.

```
<iframe width="800" height="800" src="scores/new?site_id=193">

<script>
    var element = document.getElementById("sidebar-wrapper");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
</script>

</iframe>
```

Comment: Is the `iframe` from the same domain?

Comment: yeah, right now everything is just local to my machine. I'm still testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a control in the iframed page

```
  //inside the iframed page
  var iframe = (function() {
      try {
          return window.self !== window.top;
      } catch (e) {
          return true;
      }
  })();

  if(iframe === true) {
    var element = document.getElementById("sidebar-wrapper");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
```

Hope this could suit your need.

Comment: @Spance this is really useful since it doesn't require any kind of connection between the 2 sites / domains.

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons you can't run javascript through iframes. There are some exceptions if you're on the same domain but for the most part you should really avoid it.

If the iframe isn't a site you can control then there's pretty much nothing you can do. If you do control the other site and it's a different domain you might be able to work with the `postMessage` functions.

Edit: Check out the docs that Mozilla has up here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

You'd need to create a listener on the inside that handles a message and hides your sidebar. Then on the parent send a message to the iframe to trigger that function.

Parent:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('#iframeID');
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('iframeTrigger');
```

Iframe:

```
window.addEventListener('iframeTrigger', hideSidebar);

function hideSidebar() {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: the site that the iframe is coming from is an app that I own and wrote myself

Answer (score 0):

This should work theoretically, and it works in `console`. But this doesn't work in the HTML, although you are trying it from the same domain, because of security reasons. I just wanted to tell my view and I tried this:

```
<iframe src="http://output.jsbin.com/figujeyiyo" frameborder="0" id="ifrm">
  Sorry, iframes not supported.
</iframe>
<script>
  console.log(document.getElementById("ifrm").contentDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("div"));
  e = document.getElementById("ifrm").contentDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  console.log(e);
  e.parentNode.removeChild(element);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the code when the page loads, you can do it like this:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     var element = document.getElementById("sidebar-wrapper");
     element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  });
```

Comment: You can't do this from the parent frame.